# iPhone Messages App-like recipient list view

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to create a message composer view on iOS which includes a recipient list just like that in iPhone built-in Messages App:

[image]

It looks just like a UITextView, but while you were entering names or numbers, it tries to match data from address book, and once matched the entered text will change into the name in address book and have a light-blue round-rectangular background.

I've checked [weiSMS](http://code.google.com/p/weisms/) but I'm afraid the source codes are too old to build for iOS 4/5, just wondering if there's any framework/components I can re-use, or any other resources that I can learn how to do it from scratch. Please kindly show me some pointers and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course!  Why, just earlier today, I found this [control](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/titokenfield) up on CocoaControls.com.  It's crude, yes, but I'm sure with a little tweaking, you can get rid of that nasty light blue default background for the tokens.

Comment: Looks exactly like what I need, thanks a lot and I'll try it out!